# I want simplify those CSS by using LESS,how?

Tags: css, less

```
li:nth-child(1){
      .icon{
        background: url('ico_1.png')  no-repeat;`image1`
      }
     }

li:nth-child(2){
      .icon{
        background: url('ico_2.png')  no-repeat;`image2`
      }
     }

li:nth-child(3){
      .icon{
        background: url('ico_3.png')  no-repeat;`image3`
      }
     }
```

Comment: First, _wut_. Second, what do you actually want?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Less, but I use sass and you can use a loop.

You should read [this page](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature)

If I'm not wrong, the less code would be something like that (couldn't try as I use sass):

```
.generate-icons(3);

.generate-icons(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  li:nth-child(@{i}) .icon {
    background-image:url('ico_@{i}.png')
  }
  .generate-icons(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thx,dude,you help me a lot.YOU ARE THE REAL MVP!

Comment: I'm glad i could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all . that's not good CSS . first `{` between `li:nth-child()` and `.icon` and the last `}` are not needed. the correct CSS form would be `li:nth-child() .icon { }`

Second, what are `image1` ,`image2`, `image3` ? that's also not standard css

With less you can do the following

```
li  {
  .icon {
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     /* all background common styles here */
  }
 $:first-child .icon {
     background-image:url('ico_1.png')
  }  
 $:nth-child(2) .icon {
     background-image:url('ico_2.png')
  }  
 $:nth-child(3) .icon {
     background-image:url('ico_3.png')
  }  
}
```

I know this does not necessarily simplify css , but give me more information about the html structure and i might be able to help you more

Comment: Sorry dude,maybe I was not make it clear.
All I want is loop, I want use a looper to finish it.Not the structure I'm care,it is about loop.
Can you solve?